# Return multiple items from a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I would like to ask how I can return just the for each loop

current im getting a not all code paths return a value .

```
public Config getConfigSingle(string CID, string name)
{
    var raw = db.ap_GetInfo(CID, name);

    foreach (var item in raw.ToList())
    {
        return new Config
        {
            Name = item.Name.ToString(),
            Value = item.Value.ToString(),
        };
    }       
}

public partial class ClubConfig
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks M

Comment: *how I can return just the for each loop?* What are you actually trying to return? It is unclear from your question.

Comment: its just a stored procedure send two items and I get two back

Comment: And you want to return those two items?

Comment: Do you want to return the first found element only?

Comment: @Miky I've updated your title to remove both the question and to reflect what you seem to want, based on your comments on the answers below.  If this is incorrect, please revise it to reflect your intent.

Comment: @DavidL thanks :) im still look at it all now

Comment: If the list were empty, then you wouldn't get to the `return`. That is the reason for this particular errormessage.

Comment: @Miky So do you just want to return the first item in the list (if it exists)?

Comment: There is an inconsistency in your code: your return type (`Config`) and the wordt "Single" in the method name suggest a single return value. But the usage of `foreach` suggest multiple values (although you use just the first). Please add to your question what should happen when `raw` contains 0, 1 or more results.

Comment: @Carl nope both items return as strings but not in a list the code works just says not all paths return a value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `yield`:

```
public IEnumerable<Config> getConfigSingle(string CID, string name)
{
    var raw = db.ap_GetInfo(CID, name);

    foreach (var item in raw.ToList())
    {
        yield return new Config
        {
            Name = item.Name.ToString(),
            Value = item.Value.ToString(),
        };
    }       
}
```

Comment: chucks up issue with my interface but i can figure that out, if this works Ill accept your answer Thanks M

Comment: um iv got it working but this is still returning a list isnt it? I still want 2 single stings but not in an array

Comment: @Miky I think that, you want to ask a new question. You can get strings with `.Name` and `.Value`

Comment: I can already get the strings single in my code in this question its more the fact its says not all paths return a value

Comment: thanks for all your help at least I know whats happening better and I can carry on working :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use LINQ to build your object to return:

```
public List<Config> getConfigSingle(string CID, string name)
{
var raw = db.ap_GetInfo(CID, name);

return raw.Select(r => new Config 
                        { 
                           Name = r.Name.ToString(), 
                           Value = r.Value.ToString()
                        }).ToList();
```

}

Comment: I don't want to return a '<list>' although I know this will work

Comment: remove the `ToList` and return an `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 2):

You must return a value for each code path. If you collectio in the foreach is empty, the method would return nothing. Add a return null at the end.

```
public Config getConfigSingle(string CID, string name)
{
    var raw = db.ap_GetInfo(CID, name);

    foreach (var item in raw.ToList())
    {
        return new Config
        {
            Name = item.Name.ToString(),
            Value = item.Value.ToString(),
        };
    }  
    return null;
}
```